# Locate all services running under a particular user account?

Tags: service

Suppose an old administrator left the organization. He left no documentation, and had many things set up "his way", while ignoring best practice.

I want to delete his account, though this will likely break many valid services (this is how he had it set up).

How would I search the network (or AD) to locate any services running under a particular user account?

Must I log into each server and check its services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can review the security log on your Domain Controllers after he's gone and his account should no longer be in active use. Look for successful account logons for his account and what machine(s) they're coming from.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like

```
foreach($comp in Get-ADComputer)
{
    if($(gwmi win32_service -Computername $comp).StartName -eq "DudeWhoLeft")
    {
         Write-Host "I FOUND A SERVICE ON $comp THAT RUNS AS DUDEWHOLEFT!!!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will be sure to give this a go first before I try the manual solution.